# Is boost message queue thread safe & process safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm trying to use **boost::interprocess::message_queue** to send messages from one process to another and have finished the sender code. I'm wondering if this message queue is process safe but have not found any official announcement about it, while among the related questions in stackoverflow community, there're only answers about whether **shared resources in boost::interprocess** are thread safe, which does not mention **message_queue**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes. Boost take cares all the synchronization for message queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by iamnoten, yes it is thread/process safe. Question closed.